# Programmatic state changes not working in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to get states to change with the visual state manager through code.

I am using:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.LayoutRoot, "stateRegistration", true);
```

But it doesn't seem to want to work, I have create an event handler and also a listener but it there's no state changed when using that code.

Can anyone help me out.

XAML CODE (Code Snippet):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="897" Height="699">
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<VisualState x:Name="stateRegistration">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="870" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="RegisterContent" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="880" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="HomeContent" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnRegRegister" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnRegRegister" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest adding some more details about what you're doing, and also the XAML. That may be helpful in understanding your problem and figuring out a solution.

Comment: what is your this.LayoutRoot?

Comment: this.LayoutRoot is the LayoutRoot layer, basically the canvas

Comment: It is strange that the visual state name starts with the lower case, it seems that it is a visual state of your own control, and the `LayoutRoot` control has this type. But it is impossible for me to help with custom controls if I can't see their code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is strange behavior with the `VisualStateManager`: its states must be situated not in the control, but in the child control.

It means, that the `GoToState` method should be called with the `this` parameter instead of the `this.LayoutRoot` parameter, but definitions of state groups must be situated inside the `Grid`:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "stateRegistration", true);
```

I don't know where to get the `ExtendedVisualStateManager` class so I use the default one.

Also if any animation of the state storyboard fails - all animations are cancelled. So try this code sample with two animations, it must work:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="897" Height="699">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="stateRegistration">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnRegRegister" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnRegRegister" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Button x:Name="btnRegRegister" Content="Some button" Click="btnRegRegister_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, using this.Layout was the problem, all working now. Thanks a lot